# Do programs run in Linux in Wine benefit from DEP and ASLR?

Tags: threat-mitigation, aslr, dep

Do programs run in Linux in Wine benefit from mitigation techniques DEP and ASLR?

Comment: According to a ctf write up (https://ctftime.org/writeup/6942) it doesn't support ASLR but does DEP and page protection. As it is not a credible source I cannot write a answer for it